# POST method for zoho books using Json for Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, post, zoho

I'm trying to include Zoho Books API within my swift app. 
I would like to create an item using the POST method, but I keep having an error message saying my JSONString is wrong.

Here is what zoho documentation request to send, using POST method, in order to create and item :

```
 https://books.zoho.com/api/v3/items
  ?authtoken=e07119171812c29b3a0dacdb79a57e3f
  &organization_id=10234695
  &JSONString={
      "name": "Hard Drive",
      "description": "500GB, USB 2.0 interface 1400 rpm, protective hard case.",
      "rate": 120.00,
      "account_id": "460000000000388",
      "tax_id": "460000000027005"
}
```

Here is what I make. I sense somehow my JSONString doesnt meet the expected format...

```
let postData = [ 
            "authtoken" : "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ",
            "organization_id" : "XXXXXXXXXXX",
            "JSONString" :
                [
                "name": "Hard Drive",
                "description": "500GB, USB 2.0 interface 1400 rpm, protective hard case.",
                "rate": 120.00,
                "account_id": "460000000000388",
                "tax_id": "460000000027005"
                ]
            ] as [String : Any]

        var request = URLRequest(url: NSURL(string:"https://books.zoho.eu/api/v3/items")! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postData, options: [])
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON
            { response in
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    let zohoResponse: [String: AnyObject] = JSON as! [String : AnyObject]
                    print(zohoResponse)
                }
        }
```

And the answer :

```
["code": 4, "message": Invalid value passed for JSONString]
```

I manage well to make GET request so I believe it should be manageable to use POST method within my swift app as well.

Many thanks for your help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE :

The solution I found was by sending the post request using string parameters instead of JSON one.

If you have an alternative solution, i'm interrested, yet the one I use works...

```
class func sendPostZoho(url : String, dataArray : [String: AnyObject] , completionHandler : @escaping ([String : AnyObject])->()) {
    let jsonstring  = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dataArray, options: [])
    let convertedString = String(data: jsonstring, encoding: .utf8)

    let percentageString = convertedString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "%22")
    var request3 = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request3.httpMethod = "POST"
    let StringtoPost = "&JSONString=" + percentageString!

    request3.httpBody = StringtoPost.data(using: .utf8)

    Alamofire.request(request3).responseJSON
        { response in

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                let DictionnaryResponse: [String: AnyObject] = JSON as! [String : AnyObject]
                completionHandler(DictionnaryResponse)
            }
    }
}
```